# SQL Server : subquery to return the latest cost revision of a unit of inventory on hand

Tags: sql-server, subquery, fifo

I have 2 tables that I am trying to marry together to end up with a result, which tells me the standard cost of the item that is still on hand (based on a FIFO costing method). The first table is inventory receipts , which tells me the parts left to consume and the transaction dates of those receipts. The second is a standard cost view which tells me the cost history of the item (rev = revision number which increases by 1 each time the standard cost of the part gets updated).

I currently have a solution which works using TOP 1 and ordering by DESC on effective date of cost, however, when I run this for the entire inventory list of the company , it takes over 16 minutes due to the TOP 1 sub-query inefficiency and cost.

Sample data (inventory receipts on hand):

```
partID  warehouse     transDate  seqn orderID   qtytoconsume
-------------------------------------------------------------
P0003   W01 2019-01-24 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0187 2
P0003   W01 2018-06-24 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0099 3
P0003   W01 2018-11-24 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0165 1
P0003   W04 2018-12-14 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0175 1
P0002   W02 2019-01-14 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0184 4
P0002   W02 2019-03-24 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0199 1
P0002   W03 2018-05-27 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0093 1
P0002   W03 2018-12-06 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0171 2
P0001   W04 2018-09-09 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0146 5
P0001   W02 2019-04-22 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0200 4
P0001   W03 2019-03-29 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0200 2
P0001   W02 2018-02-14 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0061 1
```

and standard cost view:

```
partID  document    effdate            rev  costamt
-----------------------------------------------------
P0001   IV0001  2018-01-28 00:00:00.000 1   1000.00
P0001   IV0023  2018-06-30 00:00:00.000 2   1200.00
P0001   IV0045  2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 3   1300.00
P0002   IV0001  2018-01-28 00:00:00.000 1   45.00
P0002   IV0013  2018-04-10 00:00:00.000 2   42.00
P0002   IV0045  2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 3   56.00
P0003   IV0001  2018-01-28 00:00:00.000 1   23400.00
P0003   IV0003  2018-02-20 00:00:00.000 2   11200.00
P0003   IV0045  2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 3   15000.00
P0003   IV0047  2019-02-27 00:00:00.000 4   13400.00
P0003   IV0078  2019-05-03 00:00:00.000 5   14670.00
```

And my result (which equals my expected result), but for large row sets is less than ideal.

```
partID  warehouse   transDate     seqn  orderID qty costamt
-------------------------------------------------------------
P0003   W01 2019-01-24 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0187 2   15000.00
P0003   W01 2018-06-24 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0099 3   11200.00
P0003   W01 2018-11-24 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0165 1   11200.00
P0003   W04 2018-12-14 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0175 1   11200.00
P0002   W02 2019-01-14 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0184 4   56.00
P0002   W02 2019-03-24 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0199 1   56.00
P0002   W03 2018-05-27 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0093 1   42.00
P0002   W03 2018-12-06 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0171 2   42.00
P0001   W04 2018-09-09 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0146 5   1200.00
P0001   W02 2019-04-22 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0200 4   1300.00
P0001   W03 2019-03-29 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0200 2   1300.00
P0001   W02 2018-02-14 00:00:00.000 1   ORD0061 1   1000.00
```

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    ioh.*, sc.costamt, sc.effdate
FROM
    inventoryonHand ioh
LEFT JOIN 
    standardcosts sc ON sc.partID = ioh.partID
                     AND sc.effdate = (SELECT TOP 1 sc2.effDate
                                       FROM standardcosts sc2
                                       WHERE sc2.partID = sc.partID
                                         AND sc2.effDate < ioh.transDate
                                       ORDER BY sc2.partID ASC, sc2.effDate DESC);
```

Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it (if your consider partID   and transdate can be unique into your inventoryonHand table, otherwhise use partition by on his key) :

```
select * from (
   select f1.*, 
   f2.effdate, f2.costamt, f2.rev,
   row_number() over(partition by f1.partid, f1.transdate order by f2.effdate desc, f2.rev desc) as lasteffDaterank
   from inventoryonHand f1
   left outer join standardcosts f2 on f1.partid=f2.partid and f2.effDate < f1.transDate
) tmp 
where lasteffDaterank=1
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for more or less. Creative in that the row_number incorporates the partition on the one date and the ordering on the effdate. I knew it has to be something like this. I'm assuming this should be very efficient for copious amounts of records. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to simplify the subquery using `max()`.

```
(SELECT max(sc1.effdate)
        FROM standardcosts sc2
        WHERE sc2.partid = sc.partid
              AND sc2.effdate < ioh.transdate)
```

For performance try an index on `standardcosts (partid ASC, effdate DESC)`.

Comment: This works, and is about 100- 150 % times faster. Thanks. I don't believe I can index standardcosts because it is a view in our database.

Answer (score 1):

You can ty this too, not really sur its better ;)

```
select f1.*, f3.*
from inventoryonHand f1
outer apply
(
  select top 1 f2.costamt from standardcosts f2 
  where f1.partid=f2.partid and f2.effDate < f1.transDate
  order by f2.effdate desc, f2.rev desc
) f3
```

Comment: This also works. Not too familiar with outer & cross apply as I tend to use joins and/or sub-queries instead. Quicker than my solution though.